# Converting from HTML+SVG file to Image is working but the Converting from the same Html+Svg string content to Image is not working in C#?

Tags: c#, html, image, svg

I have a html+svg file, when i convert this to image using The below code its working fine i,e) i am getting the actual image.

```
 private void NavigateLinkLabelLinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
       {
       pictureBox.Image =
       new HtmlToBitmapConverter()
       .Render(new Uri(urlTextBox.Text), size);
       }
```

[Image - Using URI method converting - working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBenm.png)

But when i convert the same html+Svg string contents to image usng the below code is not working.

```
 private void RenderHtmlToBitmapLinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox.Image =
                new HtmlToBitmapConverter()
                    .Render(htmlTextBox.Text, size);
        }
```

[Image - Using Rendering method converting - Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRLUs.png)

**the Class implementation is below.**

public class HtmlToBitmapConverter
        {
            private const int SleepTimeMiliseconds = 5000;

```
        public Bitmap Render(string html, Size size)
        {
            var browser = CreateBrowser(size);

            browser.Navigate("about:blank");
            browser.Document.Write(html);

            return GetBitmapFromControl(browser, size);
        }

        public Bitmap Render(Uri uri, Size size)
        {
            var browser = CreateBrowser(size);

            NavigateAndWaitForLoad(browser, uri, 0);

            return GetBitmapFromControl(browser, size);
        }

        public void NavigateAndWaitForLoad(WebBrowser browser, Uri uri, int waitTime)
        {
            browser.Navigate(uri);
            var count = 0;

            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(SleepTimeMiliseconds);

                Application.DoEvents();
                count++;

                if (count > waitTime / SleepTimeMiliseconds)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (browser.Document.Body == null)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            HideScrollBars(browser);
        }

        private void HideScrollBars(WebBrowser browser)
        {
            const string Hidden = "hidden";
            var document = (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document.DomDocument;
            var style = (IHTMLStyle2)document.body.style;
            style.overflowX = Hidden;
            style.overflowY = Hidden;
        }

        private WebBrowser CreateBrowser(Size size)
        {
            var 
                newBrowser =
                    new WebBrowser
                    {
                        ScrollBarsEnabled = false,
                        ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
                        Size = size
                    };

            newBrowser.BringToFront();

            return newBrowser;
        }

        private Bitmap GetBitmapFromControl(WebBrowser browser, Size size)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

            NativeMethods.GetImage(browser.Document.DomDocument, bitmap, Color.White);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

If the second option working then i can convert html string into image directly without writing into the file and then converting the same using first method.

Help appreciated.

Comment: finally , writing a html file locally and read back and converting to image.